# Как дебажить внешние библиотеки?

Tags: java

В проекте, некорректно работает одна из внешних либ, подключил соурс - теперь вижу код. Но брэйкпоинты не срабатывают. Как дебажить эти библиотеки?

Среда разработки Inteliji IDEA.
Дебаг при выполнении программы.

Comment: Среда разработки? Совпадает ли версии скомпилированного кода и исходного кода библиотеки? Дебаг непосредственно при выполнении или подключаетесь к процессу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в объектнике убраны ссылки на номера строк исходника дебажить не получиться. Вы сможете видеть только вход и выход из функций.